# Find the Volume Contained Inside a Sphere and Cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

Find the volume of the region that lies inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4.$

I've attempted to break this down into 2 sections: a pure cylinder, which continues until it hits the edges of the sphere, and then 2 "caps." I believe the overall shape looks like a pill. The integrals I've arrived at look like this:

For the cylinder:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}rdzdrd\theta$

And for the caps:

$2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\int_{0}^{2}\rho^2 sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$

For the cylinder, I simply plugged $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ into $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ to arrive at $r= -\sqrt3, \sqrt3$. For the sphere, I got $\phi=\frac{\pi}{6}$ based on the fact that the arm is $\sqrt3$ in the z direction and 1 in the radial direction (based on the cylinder). However, the answer I get with these integrals is wrong. Where am I screwing this up?

Comment: It will be simpler if you compute the volume of the sphere outside the cylinder first.

Comment: Achille, why would that be easier? I need to find the volume of the pill shape based on limits obtained through the crossover points of the 2 equations, what advantage would calculating the volume of the sphere give me?

Comment: If you intersect what's outside the cylinder with a plane $z = const$. the cross sectional area is $\pi(c^2 - z^2)$ where $c^2 = 4-1 = 3$. The volume outside the cylinder is equal to $\int_{-c}^c \pi (c^2 - z^2) dz$, does this expression looks familiar?

Comment: Your integral for the caps actually picks up a bit more since you have $0\leq \rho \leq 2$.  You would be calculating the volume of a cone plus the caps.  To correct this, you should us $\sqrt{3} \sec \phi \leq \rho \leq 2$, where the lower inequality comes from the plane $z=\sqrt{3}$.  Alternatively, you could just compute the whole thing as one integral in cylindrical coordinates: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} r \: dz \: dr \: d\theta$.